# True Conditional Formatting Rule with changing values and multiple cells

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, conditional-statements

After hours of research and failed attempts, I finally decided to ask the question myself.

I want to apply 3 set of rules to a particular cell, which are as follow:

*(note that H5 is Value, I5 is LoLo, J5 is Lo, K5 is Hi and L5 is HiHi)*

```
Red: =OR($H$5<$I$5,$H$5>$L$5)
Yellow: =OR(AND($H$5>$K$5,$H$5<$L$5),AND($H$5<$J$5,$H$5>$I$5))
Green: =AND($H$5>$J$5,$H$5<$K$5)
```

[image: You are seeing this 5th column]

The value shown in green at Column H is dynamic (changes every minute **automatically**), while the others are fixed.

I will show you the VBA rule I've written now for Red (it doesn't work)

```
Range(CurrentValue_Loc).Select 'CurrentValue_Loc = H5 in this case
If (ActiveCell.Value < Range(LoLo_Loc).Value Or ActiveCell.Value > Range(HiHi_Loc).Value) Then
ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
```

This "works" **once** but it's not an actual rule. It basically formats the cell when the macro runs at t=0, but in 5min, even if the value does not fulfil my rule anymore, the format will not change.

I fully understand why it does not work, but I don't know how to make it work. Hopefully I was clear enough.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you run your macro again at t=5min, does it correctly update the color?

Comment: yes it does because then the 2nd or 3rd rule becomes True so the colour is updated. If I don't run the macro at t=5, no colour change though. I would like the colours to update without me running the macro again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this via Conditional Formatting:
Apply the following as three separate rules to cell `H5`:

`Red: =OR($H5<$I5,$H5>$L5)`

`Yellow: =OR(AND($H5>$K5,$H5<$L5),AND($H5<$J5,$H5>$I5))`

`Green: =AND($H5>$J5,$H5<$K5)`

Note the lack of `$` in front of the row reference. 
Now you can use the format painter to drag these rules (and their now relative references) down column H.

Comment: Nice and easy, that's how it should be. In fact dragging it down doesnt work, but if you copy the first H5 to H6 it works so I'll just build a macro that copies H5 to H6, then to H7, to H8 ... Not the smartest way but it works... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not work, depending on exactly what you mean when you say that the values update "automatically", but generally, the way to get a macro to run whenever a value changes is to wrap it in the Worksheet change event.

To do this, in your VBA editor, on the left side, double click the name of the sheet containing the cells this macro needs to target. There are two boxes at the top of your editing window. From the left dropdown, select "Worksheet", from the one on the right, select "Change". At that point, the editor should auto-populate the shell of a `Worksheet_Change` sub. Putting your code in there will cause it to run anytime a value on the worksheet changes.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that.
By automatically I meant that the values are updated from a server, so pressing F9 would update the value. 

I think it should indeed do the trick, I'll keep you updated!

Comment: I fear this will be slow if I don't code it properly. Can you please edit your initial response showing the proper code for a loop doing this over all rows from H5:HX where X is last filled row? Thank you very much!

Comment: Added a second answer about how to do this via Conditional formatting, as it looks like your original intention was. There are many answers on SO about efficient looping. I'd refer you to those. Cheers!